# AWS textract: UnsupportedDocumentException for PNG and JPG images. Error occurs only in production and not locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, amazon-textract

I'm getting the following error when I deploy A FastAPI app to AWS Lambda that uses the AWS Textract service. The strange thing is that, it works perfectly fine in my local development environment, but throws this error when I deploy it.
Error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.UnsupportedDocumentException: An error occurred (UnsupportedDocumentException) when calling the AnalyzeDocument operation: Request has unsupported document format
```

Following is my code:

```
def extractImage(form_image: bytes = File()):

    response = textractclient.analyze_document(
        Document={
            "Bytes": form_image,
        },
        FeatureTypes=["FORMS"],
    )
```

The images that I've tried are png and jpg images and not pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the file pointer for any other purpose than this function call ?

I just had the same error when trying to call `client.analyze_document` on the open file using the sample code provided by [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/analyzing-document-text.html). They give the following code :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85oCR.png)

But it turned out (in my case), that calling `image = Image.open(img_file)` was actually changing the bytes of the file pointer and made it not working anymore. It might be the same in your case if you are doing something similar.